# Python3 Adding/Iterating on a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to sum each pair of values in this a list. Here's a short example, but I'd like my function to work with any length list.

So, for x = [1,2,3] I'd like to return the value of 12. I want to condense this:

```
y = 0
for i in x:
    y += x[0] + x[1] 
    y += x[1] + x[2]
    y += x[0] + x[2]
return y
```

I'm not sure if my question is clear, and I'll clarify if there are any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(x)-1): 
        for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
            sum+=x[i]+x[j]
```

Hopefully I wrote this right, it's a been a bit since I touched Python.  But essentially, you have marker one and marker two - marker one starts at 0 and counts up every time the outer loop increments, and j starts at i+1 and counts up to the end of the array.  Then you sum i and j, and by doing so, you eventually sum all combinations together.  It's len(x)-1 because i stops at the second to last result (and indexes start at 0, so len(x) is 1 more than the value of the last index, but range doesn't include the end value), and j stops at the last index (len(x)-1).

Answer (score 0):

Try combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [1,2,3]
y = 0
for p in combinations(x, 2):
    y += sum(p)
```

[Combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
y = sum( sum(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations( x, 2 ) )
```